# Ordinary differential equation with Boundary value conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(t)$ be the solution to the ordinary differential equation
$$
f′(t)=2f(t),
$$
with the boundary condition $f(0)=3$, then $f(1)=?$

Give me a hint if you do not want to provide full answer. What I did was

I have integrated above ode like so:-
$$
F(t) = [f(t)]^2 + C = f(t)
$$
applying boundary condition, $C$ comes out to be: $9+C=3$ giving $C=-6$

So general solution would be:
$$
[f(t)]^2 - f(t) - 6 = 0
$$
How can I guess value for 2nd condition of BVP?, also there is only one constant. How is it a  BVP?

Comment: derivative of $[f(t)]^2$ is $2f(t)f^\prime(t)$ not $2f(t) $ as you seem to have assumed. look up separation of variables or exponential growth models.

Comment: the solution is $y(x)=3e^{2x}$

Answer (score 1):

You have a separable differential equation
$$
\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}=2.
$$
Integrating from $t=0$ to $t=1$, you get
$$
\ln f(1)-\ln f(0)=\int_0^1\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\,dt = \int_0^1 2\,dt=2.
$$
I suppose you can take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $f(t) = c_1e^{c_2t}$

It's given that $f(0) = 3$ so $c_1 = 3$.

Differentiating gives $f'(t) = c_1c_2e^{c_2t}$

Plugging in the differential equation: $f′(t)=2f(t)$ gives $c_1c_2e^{c_2t} = 2c_1e^{c_2t}$

Cancelling the $c_1$ and the $e^{c_2t}$ gives $c_2 = 2$.

Thus: $f(t) = 3e^{2t}$